# mGWT debugging on Android emulators

Tags: debugging, android-emulator, mgwt

I’m developing with MGWT 2.0.1 for iOS and Android platforms.
I need to debug my application on Cordova emulators and I read the article http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/07/mgwt-super-dev-mode.html?m=1  for using Super Dev Mode with MGWT. I followed all instructions until the end of the article, so I can view the choice “Super Dev Mode: On” that you display as the latest image.

Now, how can I insert a breakpoint on app client-side and track the execution on Java source code?

To complete my question, I report you that I connected a Cordova-Android emulator with the remote debugger in Developer Chrome Tools. 
I uploaded two snapshots here to explain better my situation: I cannot see Java sources:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByBoszEV6J7rfnlZX29JTFFvUVkwLVNtZlBSalZqSHhJQVVZNThfem5FNVJPcGprV3g1enM&usp=sharing

How can I solve this issue?
Thank you very much,
best regards,

Dario

Answer (score 0):

The blog post you linked is a bit outdated, maybe the [mgwt wiki](https://github.com/mgwt/mgwt/wiki/Set-up-Super-dev-mode-with-GWT-2.7) is more helpful.

As for the Java sources, the tricky bit on Android is when you try to load the source maps. If you try to load them from `localhost`, this will be interpreted as the Android emulator's localhost (which is `10.0.2.2`). You can check if this is happening in the network tab.

Can you provide more information, which GWT version are you using? 2.7.0? What value did you give the `-bindAddress` parameter?